# How to test a compiled function?

Tags: common-lisp

I have a function `do-something`, and a function `my-function` of the form :

```
(defun my-function ((object object))
  (if (do-something)
    5
    6))
```

`do-something` and `my-function` are in `my-package` package.

In `my-package/tests` package, I want to do the following :

```
(deftest "Test my-function"
  (flet ((my-package::do-something ()
           t))
    (assert-is (my-package::my-function) 5))

  (flet ((my-package::do-something ()
           nil))
    (assert-is (my-package::my-function) 6)))
```

The goal is to test if `my-function` behaves correctly, and I would like to keep it as a function (not a macro), and without injecting functions into via the args. In C I could mess with the linker.

Each time I want to run all the updated code and tests, I do the following in the REPL :

```
(ql:quickload :my-system)
(asdf:test-sytem :my-system/tests)
```

But it seems it compiles `my-function`, so even if I do an `flet` on the `do-something` function in the test file, the behaviour does not change.

I would like to programmatically test `my-function`, is there a way to do that ?

Comment: FLET creates local lexical functions. You might want to use a global function. See `(setf (symbol-function 'my-package::do-something) your-function)`...

Comment: Problem solved, I thought `do-something` was embedded and compiled into `my-function` code. Thank you ! <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions defined by `flet` (or `labels`) have lexical scope, i. e., they exist only in the `flet` body.  It does not affect the dynamic environment.

There is no explicit support for dynamically rebinding functions, but you can use something like this:

```
(defmacro with-rebound-fun ((name args &body fun-body) &body body)
  (let ((saved (gensym)))
    `(let ((,saved (symbol-function ',name)))
       (setf (symbol-function ',name) (lambda ,args ,@fun-body))
       (unwind-protect (progn ,@body)
         (setf (symbol-function ',name) ,saved)))))
```

This is a bit hackish though, and it could break some assumptions an implementation may make about redefining functions.  In particular, the symbol might carry additional meta information about the function, which does not get changed.  It also will not work where the original function is inlined.

Comment: "In particular, the symbol might carry additional meta information about the function" what are you refering to (curiosity) ?

Comment: @Fnifni: for example documentation, type information, but that's implementation dependent.